# unable to invoke ApplyClientBehavior method in WCF app consuming from WPF app

Tags: c#, wpf, wcf

unable to hit ApplyClientBehavior method

using System.ServiceModel.Description;

```
namespace Utils.CMSAuth
{
    public class AuthorizationHeaderEndpointBehavior : IEndpointBehavior
    {
        public void ApplyClientBehavior(ServiceEndpoint endpoint, System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ClientRuntime clientRuntime)
        {
            clientRuntime.ClientMessageInspectors.Add(new AuthorizationHeaderMessageInspector(TokenGenerator.GetToken()));
        }
        public void AddBindingParameters(ServiceEndpoint endpoint, System.ServiceModel.Channels.BindingParameterCollection bindingParameters)
        {
        }

        public void ApplyDispatchBehavior(ServiceEndpoint endpoint, System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.EndpointDispatcher endpointDispatcher)
        {
        }

        public void Validate(ServiceEndpoint endpoint)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Not hitting ApplyClientBehavior method.

Added behavior at web.config side.

```
<extensions>
    <behaviorExtensions>
        <add name="AuthorizationHeaderMessageInspector" type="Utils.CMSAuth.CustomBehaviorExtensionElement, Utils, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
    </behaviorExtensions>
</extensions>
```

Comment: If it's a **WCF server application**, I suggest you try it out with code: client.Endpoint.Behaviors.Add(new AuthorizationHeaderEndpointBehavior());

Answer (score 1):

You can add behavior to the client via code like this:

```
client.Endpoint.Behaviors.Add(new AuthorizationHeaderEndpointBehavior(null, true, true));
```

You can also try modifying the client's **app.config** configuration file. This post explains it better:

[ApplyClientBehavior not called (sometimes) in IOperationBehavior](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/707aa031-f4ff-47ab-ba5b-730f7930605e/applyclientbehavior-not-called-sometimes-in-ioperationbehavior?forum=wcf)

Adding behavior to the client side with code typically looks like this:

```
using System.ServiceModel.Description;

MyServiceClient client = new MyServiceClient();


MyBehavior behavior = new MyBehavior();

client.Endpoint.Behaviors.Add(behavior);
```